# How to divide class source files even though one module

Tags: python

For management, I want to divide source files at both aspects of namespace and directory.

Aspect of directory which I want:

```
SomeProject
  +- somepackage
  |    +- __init__.py
  |    +- foo.py
  |    +- bar.py
  :
  :
```

And aspect of namespace:

```
SomeProject
  +- package somepackage
  |    +- <module>
  |    +- class Foo
  |    +- class Bar
  :
  :
```

But python regards publicly-named file as module, then extra namespace hierarchies will be built.

```
SomeProject
  +- package somepackage
  |    +- <module>
  |    +- module foo
  |    |    +- class Foo
  |    +- module bar
  |         +- class Bar
  :
  :
```

One of well known solution is to import submodules in `__init__.py`.

`SomeProject/somepackage/__init__.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

from .foo import Foo
from .bar import Bar
```

This allows library users to import classes like as desired hierarchy structure.
But actual hierarchy is not changed, and API document generators such as sphinx will read actual hierarchy.

Execution result:

```
>>> from SomeProject.somepackage import Foo
>>> type(Foo())
<class 'SomeProject.somepackage.foo.Foo'>
```

Such documents may confuse users, so I want to make to match actual namespace hierarchy with first requirement too.

I found an approach, which uses `exec`.

`SomeProject/somepackage/__init__.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys
import os
import codecs

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
with codecs.open(dir + "/foo.py", "r", "utf-8") as file:
    exec("".join(file.readlines()))
with codecs.open(dir + "/bar.py", "r", "utf-8") as file:
    exec("".join(file.readlines()))
```

Then following result will be obtained:

```
>>> from SomeProject.somepackage import Foo
>>> type(Foo())
<class 'SomeProject.somepackage.Foo'>
```

This code behave perfectly desired, but seems terrible hack.

Are there more excellent solutions?

Comment: 1. You should provide the correct API docs with tools of your choice. If a user generates it himself using other tools, it's his problem, not yours. 2. From looking at one of the projects with a sphinx generated documentation on github, with the same style of imports in its  `__init__.py`, no tricks or hacks should be necessary to do it right.